# How to migrate Realm DataBase to shared(AppGroup) in Swift?

Tags: swift, realm, dbmigrate

So I have one iOS app that uses Realm database and I've been implementing new stuff with SiriKit so now I am using App Groups that are working well for NSUserDefault.

But now how can I migrate the Realm database which is the default location to a shared folder so that the Siri extension has access to these values?

This is the code that I'm going to use to read realm in the extension

```
   let fileURL = FileManager.default
        .containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.x")!
        .appendingPathComponent("default.realm")
    let config = Realm.Configuration(
        fileURL: fileURL,
        objectTypes: [x1.self, x2.self, EquipmentConsumptionDay.self])
    _ = try! Realm(configuration: config)
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this ?

Comment: Yes....let me have look in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is easy you just need to copy realm file to the new location.

```
// Migrate now the DATABASE realm
// Copy the file from the default location to the new real location
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let originalPath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!
let appGroupURL = FileManager.default
    .containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.xx.siri")!
    .appendingPathComponent("default.realm")
do{
    try _ = fileManager.replaceItemAt(appGroupURL, withItemAt: originalPath)
}
catch{
    print("Error info: \(error)")
}
```

Don't forget to make system for migration so this code just run once